# how to use gdb to explore the stack/heap?

Tags: c, debugging, gdb, heap-memory, stack-memory

Could anyone please give me a quick overview/point me to documentation of a way to inspect the stack (and heap?) of a C program? I thought this should be done with GDB, but if there are other more straighforward alternatives, then that should be fine as well.

Thanks.

Comment: What operating system do you use?

Comment: Ah, sorry, yes: OS: Ubuntu Linux, Compiler: GCC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My first approach to using GDB for debugging is to setup breakpoints. This is done like so:

```
prompt> gdb ./x_bstree.c
(gdb) #prompt
(gdb) b 123 #break at line 123
(gdb) r #start program
```

Now your program halts at line 123 of your program. Now you can examine variables in stack or heap using `print`. For stack variables just use `print <varname>`. For heap variables (pointers) use `print <*varname>`. Not sure there is anything special to do for examining stack/heap variables?

Of course to debug multi-threaded applications you would need to make it run in single-threaded mode & then dubug Otherwise it becomes difficult to predict what's happening.

For anything else there is extensive documentation of [**gdb**](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) & many sites also provide **[gdb cheat sheets](https://web.archive.org/web/20160309134607/http://erik.cabetas.com/stuff/debug/gdb-essentials.pdf)**.

Answer (score 20):

you can dump raw memory with the 'x' command

so if you want to look at bits of the stack or heap try things like

```
x/10b &stackvar
x/200b &heapvar-20
```

The last one will show you 200 bytes starting from 20 bytes before heapvar. So if you just malloced that you can see the heap header too

Comment: I like your approach! Is there any good gdb plugin that allows to examine the heap showing it's chunk data, headers, in-use bits and the like? I just found [gdb-heap](https://fedorahosted.org/gdb-heap/). Unfortunately it seems pretty outdated and unmaintained.

Answer (score 6):

View stack:

`gdb> backtrace`

View current stack frame:

`gdb> info frame`

View arguments of current stack frame:

`gdb> info args`

View local variable of current stack frame:

`gdb> info locals`

Navigate to parent stack frame:

`gdb> frame 1`

[Examining the Stack](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Stack.html#Stack)

Comment: None of that displays raw memory content.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `ddd`. [ddd manual](http://www.gnu.org/manual/ddd/html_mono/ddd.html)

Ok. Maybe I elaborate a little. I use it like this.

compile my program with debug symbols:

```
gcc -g program.c -o program
```

run `ddd`:

```
ddd program
```

In gui you can do all sorts of things, view machine code, view memory, etc. . Look around.
In manual there is also a section of examining stack. `ddd` provides good interface for you
to examine C program.

Comment: i thought ddd was just a front end for gdb, no?

Comment: I've found it more convenient than gdb. In gui you can look at several things at once. In gdb I am scrolling back all the time.

Comment: It IS just a front end for gdb, see [updated manual location](http://www.gnu.org/software/ddd/manual/html_mono/ddd.html). It can, however, be a lot more straightforward for certain types of workflow than a console-only tool.

Answer (score 0):

[core_analyzer](http://core-analyzer.sourceforge.net/) has gdb plugin and stand alone tool.
Latest version is only gdb plugin.

[gdb plugin](http://core-analyzer.sourceforge.net/index_files/Page600.html) command shows memory statistic.

```
(gdb)
heap  [/verbose or /v]  [/leak or /l]
heap  [/block or /b]  [/cluster or /c]  <addr_exp>
heap  [/usage or /u]  <var_exp>
heap  [/topblock or /tb]  [/topuser or /tu]  <num>
```

[stand alone tool](http://core-analyzer.sourceforge.net/index_files/Page1510.html) has horizontal search and vertical search and it might be near what you expect.

```
[0] Print General Core Information
[1] Find References to an Object (horizontal search)
[2] What Is This Address and Underlying Object Type (vertical search)
[3] Objects Shared Between Threads
[4] Memory Pattern Analysis
[5] Query Heap Memory Block
[6] Page Walk (check the integrity of surrounding memory blocks)
[7] Heap Walk (check the whole heap for corruption and memory usage)
[8] Biggest heap memory blocks
[9] Biggest Heap Memory Owners (variables)
[10] Heap Memory Leak Candidates
[11] Quit
```

In my case, I could not get exprected result from core_analyzer.