# Debugging memory leak issues without any tool

Tags: c, memory-management

Interviewer - If you have no tools to check how would you detect memory leak problems?

Answer - I will read the code and see if all the memory I have allocated has been freed by me in the code itself.

Interviewer wasn't satisfied. Is there any other way to do so?

Comment: Write your own (i.e. a custom allocator that reports outstanding allocations over time to a log or some other reporting sink).

Answer (score 5):

For all the implementation defined below, one needs to write wrappers for `malloc`() & `free`() functions.

1. To keep things simple, keep track of count of malloc() & free(). If not equal then you have a memory leak.
2. A better version would be to keep track of the addresses malloc()'ed & free()'ed this way  you can identify which addresses are malloc()'ed but not free()'ed. But this again, won't help much either, since you can't relate the addresses to source code, especially it becomes a challenge when you have a large source code.
3. So here, you can add one more feature to it. For eg, I wrote a similar tool for FreeBSD Kernel, you can modify the `malloc`() call to store the module/file information (give each module/file a no, you can #define it in some header), the `stack trace` of the function calls leading to this `malloc`() and store it in a data structure, along side the above information whenever a `malloc`() or `free`() is called. Use addresses returned by `malloc`() to match with it `free`(). So, when their's a memory leak, you have information about what addresses were not `free`()'ed in which file, what were the exact functions called (through the `stack trace`) to pin point it.

The way, this tool worked was, on a crash, I used to get a core-dump. I had defined globals (this data structure where I was collecting data) in kernel memory space, which I could access using `gdb` and retrieve the information.

**Edit:**

Recently while debugging a memeory leak in linux kernel, I came across this tool called `kmemleak` which implements a similar algorithm I described in point#3 above. Read under the `Basic Algorithm` section here: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kmemleak.txt

Answer (score 0):

My response when I had to do this for real was to *build* tools... a debugging heap layer, wrapped around the C heap, and macros to switch code to running against those calls rather than accessing the normal heap library directly. That layer included some fencepost logic to detect array bounds violations, some instrumentation to monitor what the heap was doing, optionally some recordkeeping of exactly who allocated and freed each block...

Another approach, of course, is "divide and conquer". Build unit tests to try to narrow down which operations are causing the leak, then to subdivide that code further.

Depending on what "no tools" means, core dumps are also sometimes useful; seeing the content of the heap may tell you what's being leaked, for example.

And so on....

Comment: with reference to your last line..how do you see the contents of a heap in core dump?

Comment: You'd need to understand how the language is obtaining and managing space for the heap. This is a near-assembler-level debugging approach.

Comment: How do you fetch a core dump at the end of the program if it doesn't fails?

Comment: Core dump is generated on a crash. For eg, a bad memory de-reference, de-referencing an address not belonging to the process etc.

Comment: Exactly, that is what I know so how will a core dump be produced when there is a memory leak? Where can I see the contents of heap after the program is finished or about to finish ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3875055/how-to-use-gdb-to-explore-the-stack-heap

Comment: It's possible to trigger coredump for debugging. But brokenfoot's pointer looks to be a good one.