# A c program to detect memory leak

Tags: c, memory-leaks

I have a code running on an embedded platform (Controller), it is regularly freezing. I think the problem is with memory leak. Is there any way to detect memory leak by writing a C program?

Comment: Your requirement is just to prove that there is some memory leak, or you want some more info like from where the memory chunks are allocated.?

Comment: i just want to prove that there is some memory leak

Comment: My usual approach is to replace the malloc/free calls with a macro or a separate function, which tracks the pointers. If possible you can use a tool like valgrind.

Comment: Read the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22316506/debugging-memory-issues-without-any-tool/22316962#22316962

Comment: Depending on the size of the embedded platform you should not do any allocations at all. If memory is severely limited then you really should try to avoid dynamic allocations *and* recursions.

Comment: For an embedded platform you might consider not using dynamic memory allocation at all. What kind of controller is it, what kind of software is it ?

Comment: Can you please elaborate on your "embedded platform (Controller)"? Is it a custom system? Is it running Linux? Some other operating system? No operating system at all? What CPU? How much RAM does it have? But most importantly, *what are you doing* that could cause memory leaks?

Answer (score 1):

Use **valgrind** to detect memory leak please follow http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/quick-start.html for quick start

Also you need to cross compile it for finding memory leak as you are using embedded system

Comment: Running Valgrind on an embedded platform, that maybe doesn't have support for it? Though if the target platform can run `gdbserver` [it might be possible](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/manual-core-adv.html#manual-core-adv.gdbserver). But we really need more information from the OP.